# How to make a grid elemet scrollable with Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a component that can display more than 2 cards, and I want my component to display 3 cards max, and allow a scroll x if there are more than 3 cards.

In my code, the 4th card always go on second row.

How to fix this ?

code :

```
<div class="m-10 w-96 border-2">
  <div class="grid w-full grid-cols-3 gap-3 overflow-x-auto">
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/xBB4HVks1o)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably gonna need a Flex-Box for that

```
<div class="m-10 w-96 border-2">
  <div class="flex w-full overflow-x-auto whitespace-nowrap gap-3">
    <button class="flex-none w-1/3 flex flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex-none w-1/3 flex flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex-none w-1/3 flex flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex-none w-1/3 flex flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no possible way with grid ?

Comment: In my humble understanding of grids, it is just the wrong technology. You gonna need a flexbox.

Comment: I understand. I wanted grid so I can make conditional classNames :/. Well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```html
<div class="m-10 w-96 border-2">
  <div class="grid w-full grid-flow-col auto-cols-[theme('spacing.28')] grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,_auto)] gap-4 overflow-x-auto">
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
    <button class="flex w-full flex-col gap-1 rounded-xl bg-blue-300 p-3 shadow-md">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have given each column a fixed width of `7rem` using `theme('spacing.28')` so that only three of them are visible in your `w-96` container. If that is not necessary then you can use something like `auto` or `max-content`.